# Strip middle of URL string out with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to take the url

```
example.com/one/two/
```

and change it to

```
example.com/two
```

but ONLY when two follows one.
Also, I can't hardcode example.com as this could change?

Any ideas? All of my attempts are deleting all of the url after one.

Thanks

edit: so /one/two becomes /two but only when /two follows /one (/one/two)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^(.*)/one/two(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ two/$1   [R,L]
```

Comment: This creates a loop and the url ends up being /two/two/two/two/two/two/two/two/two/two/ACTUAL_RESOURCE

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/one/two/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/one/two/(.*)$  two$1  [R,L]
```

If you don't want to allow extra url segments, e.g. "/one/two/three", take out the `(.*)` and `$1`.

Comment: I do want to allow extra URL segments